# Do I have need for a screen conductor (Caliburn Micro)

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm working on a single form application where I intend to open modal dialogs only. Its purpose is mostly taking input from the user to create objects to store in a database.

1. Do I have need for a screen conductor or will a Window Manager suffice? I've tried reading all I can on the subject but still I'm not sure.

   I would like the benefit of not closing down modal dialogs if a certain amount of data hasn't been filled in, so I assume this would be classed as life-cycle management, thus forcing me to use a conductor, or can just the Window Manager handle it? I was under the impression that anything that opens a new window can't be done with the conductor?
2. Also, which is better in terms of wpf: I've read about passing an instance of the window manager to each class that needs it, but also about raising an event that one class listens for and opens a window as specified in the event. Would this latter be bad as it forms a tight relationship between each class and the event handling class?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would use a conductor here, and yes it can show modal dialogs. Take a look at the [Billy Hollis Hybrid Shell](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/11/18/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-part-6d-a-billy-hollis-hybrid-shell.aspx) article to see an example application where dialogs and dirty tracking *(checking if a form has information to be saved)* are used, and here is the link for the [WPF application](http://www.4shared.com/zip/HDBydXPz/HelloScreensWPF.html) I modified which don't use MEF.
2. If always prefer to pass my dependencies around and inject them through the constructors so I won't go with raising events unless I really need to, and anyway I would use the [`EventAggregator`](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator&referringTitle=Documentation) then and not normal .NET events, the first solution is better for testability and makes it clear what each part of the application needs and what it does.

Comment: I realize that this is pretty old, but I'd love to see a WPF version of the "HelloScreens" application. I followed the link to your WPF modified version but it's also Silverlight. Is there a WPF version of this somewhere?

Comment: @Sean The link actually points to the WPF application !! It is on 4shared.com

Comment: Thanks, this app is such a big help. I downloaded the correct app the first time however I had just downloaded the original too and I had inadvertently unzipped the wrong one!

Comment: @Ibrahim Najjar, working in WPF also.  It would be great if we could still access the Hello Screens application in WPF.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Will. Unfortunately that was a long time ago. I don't have that projection anymore. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new at this but I will try to be helpful: when you run an application built with Caliburn Micro, the Window Manager is automatically used to create the startup window. Regarding the bootstrapper:

```
    protected override void Configure()
    {
    container = new CompositionContainer(new AggregateCatalog(AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>()));

    CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();

    batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
    batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
    batch.AddExportedValue(container);

    container.Compose(batch);
  }
```

You can use this instance of the window manager to manage the different dialogs. Then you just have to import the window manager in the view model needed:

```
private readonly IWindowManager _windowManager;


[ImportingConstructor]
public FooViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager)
{
  _windowManager = windowManager;
}
```

Please take a look at the samples of the caliburn micro documentation (http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/documentation) and also at this blog: http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/03/13/caliburn-micro-part-5-the-window-manager/

The communication between viewmodels is done by the event aggregator.